# Example of elements in an additive group

Tags: group-theory

Please I'm trying to find some examples of elements of order higher than 1 in a given additive group other than $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$.                                             Thanks !

Comment: Take the group $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$. It has three elements with order $2$.

Comment: Gotta look up this kind of groups, what are they called please sir ? I'm studying mathematics in french and i don't know how to look them up.

Comment: It is the Klein-four-group. I do not know the french name.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "additive group"?  Just the additive group of some ring?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $(\mathbb{R},+)$. Outside of the additive identity $0_{\mathbb{R}}$, what is the order of any other element?

Comment: But i can't find for any real number x different than the additive identity a nonzero natural number p such that p*x=0. That means that the order of any other element is infinite. But, sorry for my not well-stated question, i was looking for elements of order 2 or 3 for example.

Comment: Yes, every element has infinite order. Ah and okay, because the post reads as if you are asking for examples of order bigger than 1 in  groups other than Z/(n) .

Comment: Yes ^^, Thank you so much for your instant answer man.

Answer (score 1):

In the infinite group $(\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z,+)$, every element $p/q+\mathbf Z$ (in irreducible form) has finite order $q$.

Comment: Oh quotient groups...gotta work hard to feel this answer. Thank you so much sir even though i didn't catch it HAHA ! i'm still a beginner in this field. i'll turn back to it for sure looking for an Aha !